# Input numbers return values inputted

Tags: python, loops

I was given a problem to solve, it was like this:

> Write a program that asks the user to input numbers and to end the program type -1, after return the sum of the numbers inputted.

This is what I've done:

```
num=0
i = 0

while num != -1:                          #loop to get the numbers
    i = i + num                           #this will make the sum of the inputted numbers
    num = int(input("Input a number: "))  #save the input given into "num"
    print(num)                            #this shows the number that has been inputted by the user
    print("Input -1 to terminate")

print(i)                                  #this shows the total sum of all the inputted numbers
```

It does what it was asked, but now I want on my last print() to give the numbers the user inputted, not the sum of them all. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the user's numbers in a Python list: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

You can create a new list by doing something like `numbers = []`, which will create an empty Python list. Then, on each iteration in your while loop, you can add the number to this list by doing `numbers.append(i)`, which will add the new number to the end of this list. Once you are ready to display all the numbers, you can use a for loop to display all of the numbers that are held in the list: `for num in numbers: print(num)`

Comment: I think i understand what you've said, and it makes total sense. But i haven't learned list yet.

Comment: @Seiroh, I think that lists would be a good thing for you to learn next. Think of them just as a sequence or collection of variables. The complexity can pick up quickly, but this problem is a good introduction, where all you need a list for is really to easily store the user's inputs in a single variable.

Comment: Your method works. But i need to press -1 to end the code, and with the list the -1 appears also in the print. Any way to solve it?

Comment: @Seiroh, you should be able to do ```numbers.pop()```, which removes the last number in your list of numbers.